# Can I force my parents to give me documents needed to buy a house?

Tags: family-law, mortgage, italy

I'm in a bit of a pickle here.

I'm in the process of buying my first house and I need a document, called the **ISEE** ("Equivalent Economic Situation Indicator"), in order to get a lower interest rate on the mortgage (and pay less taxes).

To get the **ISEE** document, some other documents are needed. The majority are in regard to the financial situation of the whole familiy, including my parents.

The problem is that they are unwilling the give me those documents (or give them directly to the state body the calculates the **ISEE**, if for some reason they don't trust me).

Is there any way I can force them to produce those documents?

I'm based in Italy and I don't really care about remaining on good terms with my parents.

Comment: "don't really care about remaining in good terms with my parents": it seems you are already on not-so-good terms with your parents.  Is there some history here that might affect answers to this question?

Comment: @phoog mmmh not really. I mean, there is some personal stuff, but it would be off-topic. I just need those documents, and i think i'm not the first person with this kind of problem. My reasoning is that there has to be a way to get out of this situation without some workaround.

Comment: @Yeeter a bit of frame challenge: in Poland if you no longer have a relationship with your parents and you function effectively as a separate household under the same roof, then you can claim that and you no longer need parents financial statements. Maybe similar mechanism is in your law, too?

Comment: @Mołot eh, i called the **CAF**, which is the state body that gives you the **ISEE** document. They said that the only other thing i can do is change residency, but i prefer not to do that until i have the new house

Comment: My mother refused to fill out the FAFSA (US financial document for parents and students that's used to calculate parental contribution and how much financial aid for college) because she didn't want to document her finances. Maybe your parents feel similarly.